# I keep getting this error while running navigation with robot_pose_ekf package

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available before running costmap, tf error: Could not find a connection between 'odom' and 'base_link' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.. canTransform returned after 0.100956 timeout was 0.1.
I use robot_pose_ekf package to transform odom -> basefootprint but i don know why the transform doesn't work
this is my TF tree
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400696/i-keep-getting-this-error-while-running-navigation-with-robot_pose_ekf-package/) by [Hungnguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/105055/hungnguyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This may not help you exactly, but just to check:

1. is the input frame correctly set to base_link (the default is [base_footprint](https://github.com/ros-planning/robot_pose_ekf/blob/fd6cef32b447e8b344a1111373e515aa2f8bfc50/src/odom_estimation_node.cpp#L78))
2. and is the output frame correctly set to odom (the default is [odom_combined](https://github.com/ros-planning/robot_pose_ekf/blob/fd6cef32b447e8b344a1111373e515aa2f8bfc50/src/odom_estimation_node.cpp#L77)):

From the tf graph it seems like robot_pose_ekf is not doing the job of transforming odom to base_footprint. This could be due to parameter errors (as suggested above) or a lack of 'proper' information being fed into the odom

---

Originally posted by [ParkerRobert](https://answers.ros.org/users/56923/parkerrobert/) with karma: 113 on 2022-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0